# AWS DynamoDB Swift Query with multiple hashKeyValues

Tags: swift, amazon-dynamodb

How do I use the `AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression` and `hashKeyValues` to query multiple items? It is after all called `hashKeyValues` (plural) and it does take an `id`, but I haven't been able to get it to work with anything other than a `String`.

Assume a **Person** table with a primary key of **id**, a **name** field and it has some data with ids of 1,2,3,4, ... and the following code.

```
class Person: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {
    var id :String?
    var name :String?

    // MARK: - AWSDynamoDBModeling

    static func hashKeyAttribute() -> String! {
        return "id"
    }

    static func dynamoDBTableName() -> String! {
        return "Person"
    }
}
```

And the query code

```
    let mapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()

    let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
    /* this works
    queryExpression.hashKeyValues = "1"  
    */

    // but I really want something like...
    queryExpression.hashKeyValues = ["1", "5", "99"]

    mapper.query(Person.self, expression: queryExpression) .continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
        if (task.error != nil) {
            print("Names from IDs lookup failed: \(task.error)")
        } else if (task.result != nil) {
            let people = task.result.items as! [Person]
            for person in people {
                print("---> \(person.name)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Task result is nil")
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to use a batchGet and not a query in this case, if you know the exact keys that you need to retrieve.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/batch-operation-document-api-java.html

Sorry it is in java.